# How do you add a textbox to a skew-t plot in metpy?

Tags: metpy

I am tinkering with the skew-t notebook we did at the unidata metpy training session.  Is there a way to put a text box on or next to the skew-t that includes the information.  (CAPE = xx, the LCL is XX, etc.) I know we did subplots, but I think the skew-t is a special kind of figure that maybe has different rules?

Answer (score 1):

The `SkewT` object in MetPy is a special thing, but it has a `.ax` attribute that is a standard Matplotlib Axes you can work with as normal, including using matplotlib's `text()` plotting command:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
skew = SkewT(fig, rotation=45)

# Plot the data using normal plotting functions, in this case using
# log scaling in Y, as dictated by the typical meteorological plot
skew.plot(p, T, 'r')
skew.plot(p, Td, 'g')
skew.plot_barbs(p, u, v)
skew.ax.set_ylim(1000, 100)
skew.ax.set_xlim(-40, 60)

# these are matplotlib.patch.Patch properties
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5)

# place a text box in upper left in axes coords
skew.ax.text(0.05, 0.95, 'LCL: 757mb', transform=skew.ax.transAxes,
             fontsize=14, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
```